# unexpected callbacks behaviour in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

I've been trying to migrate my codebase from rails 5 to rails 7 and there are some issues with callbacks which I'm unable to figure out

**Issues:**

1. When multiple callbacks like `after_create_commit` and `after_update_commit` are supposed to trigger the same method say `foo` the method doesn't get called. For example:

```rb
after_create_commit :foo
after_update_commit :foo
```

But it does when I slightly change the syntax as

```rb
after_create_commit -> { foo }
after_update_commit -> { foo }
```

2. If there are multiple methods to be triggered after a callback then only the last one gets called and all the ones before it doesn't get executed, For example:

```rb
after_create_commit :foo1
after_create_commit :foo2
after_create_commit :foo3
```

here only `foo3` gets executed and `foo1`, `foo2` doesn't.

can someone explain this behaviour and what could be the proper solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

```
after_create_commit :foo
after_update_commit :foo
```

The above code will not work as we cannot register same method in `after_commit` callback on both creation and updation. Here, the latter line of `after_update_commit` overrides the previous registration and callback will run after updation only.

**Reason:**

Rails does not maintain separate callback chains for `create` and `update` internally. We can check callback chain by using `__callbacks[:commit]` method.

Also, Below code will work fine because these are procs and they will be registered as two separate procs in callback chain.

```
after_create_commit -> { foo }
after_update_commit -> { foo }
```

**Issue 2:**

```
after_create_commit :foo1
after_create_commit :foo2
after_create_commit :foo3
```

Here, All methods should execute in the order `foo3, foo2, foo1`. But, If `foo3` raises `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exception, then `foo2` and `foo1` will not execute. Please post the exact code that you are using.

Comment: This entry in the callbacks guide is also very relevant: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks